# Reducing requirements.txt

Tags: python, requirements.txt

Is there a way to reduce my requirements.txt I switched to Python a year ago and back then I did not completely understand how things work. So when I needed to create requirements.txt I just did a pip freeze and copy passed all the requirements. Today I know that I don't need them all just top-level that import other requirements is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Your requirements.txt *should* list everything, so the version of every dependency is fixed and you won’t be surprised by sudden updates introducing bugs. You may want a setup.py which lists only your direct dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few options.

### pip-tools

If you are using `pip` in your project, you can appreciate [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools). First put your requirements manually into `requirements.in`, and then with `pip-compile` you can generate the final `requirements.txt` with all dependencies. Let's say dependencies of your project are Django and Ansible. You put them into `requirements.in` like this:

```
# requirements.in
django
ansible
```

and then run `pip-compile` to get the whole dependency graph:

`$ pip-compile requirements.in`

```
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
ansible==2.9.12           # via -r requirements.in
cffi==1.14.2              # via cryptography
cryptography==3.1         # via ansible
django==1.11.29           # via -r requirements.in
jinja2==2.11.2            # via ansible
markupsafe==1.1.1         # via jinja2
pycparser==2.20           # via cffi
pytz==2020.1              # via django
pyyaml==5.3.1             # via ansible
six==1.15.0               # via cryptography
```

### Poetry

If you are using [Poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry), then you can keep adding the dependencies via `poetry add`, and eventually export them if needed. Otherwise you can skip the export step, as poetry can generate the package for distributing for you via `poetry build`:

`$ poetry add django`

```
Using version ^3.1 for django

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.4s)

Writing lock file


Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing asgiref (3.2.10)
  - Installing sqlparse (0.3.1)
  - Installing django (3.1)
```

You can find all dependencies in `pyproject.toml`. In case you need to export it into `requirements.txt`:

`$ poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt --without-hashes`

I'm using `--without-hashes`, since AppEngine has problem with it

Comment: If you use Poetry, you don’t really need a requirements.txt, since the .lock file replaces it.

Comment: yes, that's why I said "eventually export them if needed. Otherwise you can skip the export step..."